# Should an if statement be associated with else statement in ocaml?

Tags: if-statement, return, ocaml

In ocaml, I want to have many nested if statements and a return value on each of the conditions. The code is becoming complicated like this.

```
let func arg1 arg2 = 
   if condition1 then arg1+arg2
   else
   (
       //code1
       if condition2 then arg1*arg2
       else
       (
          //code2
          if condition3 then arg1+arg2
          else
          (
             //code3
          )
       )
   )
```

Instead of such nested statements can I have code like this?

```
let func arg1 arg2 = 
   if condition1 then arg1+arg2
   //code1
   if condition2 then arg1*arg2
   //code2
   if condition3 then arg1+arg2
   //code3
```

Comment: It looks like you are implementing an interpreter, so my guess is that `condition1` etc. can be written as pattern-matching clauses, which is nicely supported by the language and avoids nesting conditionals (they are more like a `switch`, but smarter). To answer the general question: no, there is no way to have early returns (except with execptions). You can use a coding style where nesting is not apparent.

Comment: @coredump. No. I am not implementing an interpreter. I just gave this example to simplify the problem. My actual return values are different and there are many code lines in between the if conditions as mentioned in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OCaml is a strongly and statically typed language, which means that the type of every expression is checked at compile-time.

Take a look at the following snippet.

```ml
if condition then true_value else false_value
```

During compilation, the type-checker will check for the following:

1. `condition` must have type `bool`;
2. `true_value` must have the same type as `false_value`;
3. The whole expression has the same type as `true_value` and `false_value`.

If any one of these statements is not true, then the compilation fails with a type error.

---

Now, let's take a look at a `if` statement, without a `else`.

```ml
if condition then true_value
```

If the condition is false, then the expression evaluates to `()`, the only value of type `unit`. Using statements 2 and 3 from before, the only type that `true_value` can have here is `unit`. That means that you can't use `int` or `string` or anything as the `true_value`.

---

Usually, deeply nested `if-else` statements is considered a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell): it may indicate that your code needs refactoring. For instance, OCaml offers [pattern-matching](https://www2.lib.uchicago.edu/keith/ocaml-class/pattern-matching.html). Depending on what your actual code looks like, it may be the way to go.

Comment: slight nit-picking: the expression does not evaluate to nothing, but to `()`, the unique value of type `unit`.

Comment: It might be simpler to say that an "if then" construct has an implizit `else ()`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use an `if` statement without a `else` if it returns a value of type `unit` (basically when it only *does* something).

```
if condition then print_int 3
```

However, in your case, you want to return a value of type `int` and as such the `else` branch is mandatory. It can nonetheless be shortened using `else if` statements.

```
if condition1 then arg1+arg2
else if condition2 then arg1*arg2
else if condition3 then arg1+arg2
else arg1
```

Note that once again, you need to use `else` at the end.

Pattern-matching can also be extended to verify some conditions using `when` clauses:

```
match 3 with
| 0 -> 0
| 1 -> 1
| x when x mod 2 = 0 -> x/2
| x when x mod 3 = 0 -> x/3
| x -> x
```

Answer (score 0):

Just fyi, you don't need all those parentheses. Anything that comes after an `else` is considered to be a single expression in the 'else' branch. You could write your code like

```
let func arg1 arg2 = 
  if condition1 then arg1+arg2 else
  (* code1 *)

  if condition2 then arg1*arg2 else
  (* code2 *)

  if condition3 then arg1+arg2 else
  (* code2 *)
```

Comment: This very much depend from what `(* code1 *)` actually is. In particular, if you have something like `if condition1 then arg1+arg2 else print_endline "in else branch"; if condition2 then ...`, the `else` will end at the semicolon (and you'll get a type error since `then` has type `int` and `else` has type `unit`). Generally speaking, putting `( ... )` or `begin ... end` around branches (both `then` and `else`) as soon as they're not completely trivial usually gives more readable and maintainable code.