# Matching element in abstract data type in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, custom-data-type

I am a beginner in OCaml. Now I am practicing some of my codes. I just tested my custom data type(I do not think this is really 'my' custom) but I met with an error,
This is the code

```
type btree =
  | Empty
  | Node of (int * btree * btree)

let rec mem : int -> btree -> bool
= fun n t ->
  match t with
    |Empty -> false
    |Node (a,b,c) -> if a = n then true
                     else if mem n b then true
                     else if mem n c then true;;
```

OCaml says that the last 'true; should be type unit but I planned that this mem function should return boolean. I do not understand why 'true' is not fit with it...
By the way, function mem is designed to check that the btree 't' contains int 'n'.

Comment: You're missing a final catch-all else branch. If omitted, the compiler will assume it just returns unit.

Comment: Related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57041443/should-an-if-statement-be-associated-with-else-statement-in-ocaml/. The problem with your program is that the last `if` needs an `else`.

Comment: You can also simplify your if-then-else nesting by using the sequential or operator `||`.

Comment: Agreed with @PatJ. In most cases, `if x then true` is superfluous.

Comment: why are you guys prefer to post your answers in the comments?))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OCaml has two forms of the `if` expression:

```
if <cond> then <exp1> else <exp2>
```

and

```
if <cond> then <exp1>
```

In the latter form, the `else` branch is omitted and defaults to `else ()` where `()` is the value of type unit. In other words, the latter form is a syntactic sugar

```
if <cond> then <exp1> ::= if <cond> then <exp1> else ()
```

Therefore, when you write, for example,

```
if friendly then "Say hello"
```

it is the same as

```
if friendly then "Say hello" else ()
```

This expression is not well-formed, since depending on the condition (`friendly`) it may return either a value of type `string` or a value of type `unit`. In OCaml, each expression should have one and only one type.

Going to your code, in particular, you have a chain of `if/then/else` expression and the last `else` expression is omitted, probably because you felt that it should default to `false` (this is not the case). A semantically correct version of your code is

```
if a = n then true
else if mem n b then true
else if mem n c then true
else false
```

However, this code could be improved. In OCaml `(||)` and `(&&)` operators are short-circuiting, i.e., in `x || y` the expression `y` is not evaluated if `x` is true. So when we have an expression of the form

```
 if <cond> then true else <bool-expr>
```

we can always rewrite it is a more concise (and easier to understand)

```
 <cond> || <bool-expr>
```

therefore, your code could be rewritten to

```
a = n || mem n b || mem n c
```

which is much short, easier to understand, and less error-prone.